# SharedPreferences and Emulator

Tags: android, emulation

I have this simple piece of code:

```
        SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.USER_DETAILS, 0);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

        //editor.putLong(Constants.USER_DETAILS_SIGNEDINON, registerResponse.getSignedInOn()); // signed in on

        editor.putLong(Constants.USER_DETAILS_SIGNEDINON, 1); // signed in on
        long test = settings.getLong(Constants.USER_DETAILS_SIGNEDINON, 2);

        if (settings.edit().commit()) {
            System.out.print("ok");
        } else {
            System.out.print("not ok");
        }
```

as you can see I have been playing around to understand what is going on.

So, I have checked the /data/data/... and the preferences file is indeed created but is empty (just the Map tag)

The test long variable returns 2, even if I set it to 1 the line before.
The commit returns true.

Am I missing something?

I have set     uses-permission android:name=android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
 though I believe this is only needed when I truly do external storage.

Regards.
David.

Comment: You need to commit the changes before you try to read the value. Add value (putLong) -> commit -> read value (getLong)

Comment: It is not working. I have adb pull the file on my computer, and the xml file is empty. I have checked the timestamp, and the file has even not been touched by the Emulator: -rw-rw-rw- root     root          148 2012-10-08 10:57 UserDetails.xml (but as you can see full permissions on the file)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this piece of code.

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(Constants.USER_DETAILS, 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();

    //editor.putLong(Constants.USER_DETAILS_SIGNEDINON, registerResponse.getSignedInOn()); // signed in on

    editor.putLong(Constants.USER_DETAILS_SIGNEDINON, 1); // signed in on

    if (editor.commit()) {
        System.out.print("ok");
    } else {
        System.out.print("not ok");
    }
    long test = settings.getLong(Constants.USER_DETAILS_SIGNEDINON, 2);
```

Comment: Already tried this one... My code is nothing more than what the tutorial says! Weird

Answer (score 3):

One thing I ran in to was that you cannot keep calling pref.edit() and expect your changes to persist. It appears that each call to pref.edit() produces a new Editor (not a singleton).

WILL NOT PERSIST:

```
pref.edit().remove("key"); // new editor created
pref.edit().commit();      // new editor created
```

WILL PERSIST:

```
Editor edit=pref.edit();   // new editor created
edit.remove("key");        // same editor used
edit.commit();             // same editor used
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext().getSharedPreferences("MyPref",  0);        0 - for private mode
Editor editor = pref.edit();
editor.putBoolean("key_name", true); // Storing boolean - true/false
editor.putString("key_name", "string value"); // Storing string
// returns stored preference value
// If value is not present return second param value - In this case null
pref.getString("key_name", null); // getting String
pref.getInt("key_name", null); // getting Integer
editor.remove("name"); // will delete key name
editor.remove("email"); // will delete key email

editor.commit(); // commit changes
editor.clear();
editor.commit(); // commit changes
```

Comment: Got it! Cheers.... settings.edit().commit() is not working... need to be changed to edit().commit()